# How can I use scripts in a static codesandbox template?

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I have created a [static codesandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/s/static-template-swt62), but can't seem to get javascript working:

```
   <html>
     <head>
     <script src="./app.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <p>Just a test</p>
       <script>console.log("heyyy")</script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
 console.log("boink")
```

The console does not show any console output at all. Are scripts not allowed in static websites without a bundler?

Comment: It seems like a webpack is clearing the console. You can tell that by hitting F12 and seeing the *"Console was cleared"* statement coming from webpack source files. Try with `alert('boink');` and it should work.

Comment: A simple `setTimeout(() => console.log("boink boink"), 1000);` will also work. Not sure why the console is cleard though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comments. It looks like there's a setting which by default causes the console to be cleared. You can change it by clicking the gear icon:

[image: gear icon]

and then changing this option (if it's enabled it will be green):

[image: clear console setting]

After turning it off, the console is not cleared anymore for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That cog icon is actually not showing in my codesandbox editor, but I disabled the setting `clear console` under `file > preferences`. Strangely, this has no effect on the initial log statements, they still don't show. But, the `setTimeout` works, so I guess the script is actually running!

Comment: I also found that `app.js` is actually a system name so that file got ignored automatically. But the console is still cleared for whatever reason.

Comment: Maybe try contacting the Codesandbox crew directly via GH: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues. Some parts of their system are open-sourced

Comment: Finally, I found that including multiple scripts doesn't work, because type checking fails for variables in external scripts (`x is not defined` when `x` comes from another file). These static templates really are not meant for use with scripting I guess. Not a real problem, but good to know!